# how to give multiple post thumbnails to a post

Tags: posts, images, post-thumbnails

[image]

the image with the red cercles are the post thumbnail images, 
i want to give each post an image of size 100px X 60px,
i dont know how to make it, this will make the website faster , becease it will load an image of 100X60 rather than an image of 1024X1024 than resize it with css, but how to give each post an image of 100X60 that i can use at this place ?
help!

Answer (score 1):

```
the_post_thumbnail( array(100, 60) );
```

use this funcation where popular posts are coming from.

Comment: i didn't understand how to use it, could you help me